# Load array by NSUserDefaults into the KeyboardViewController.swift

Tags: xcode, swift

i have this error:

Terminating app due to uncaught exception:

> 'NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException', reason: '***
>   -[NSKeyedUnarchiver decodeObjectForKey:]: cannot decode object of class (Shortcuts.NoteModel)'

I'm trying to encode `NSData` to an array. 
I saved array and sent to the keyboard.

```
func save (){

let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(scatola)


    var userDefaulte = NSUserDefaults(suiteName: "group.Allegretti.ShortcutsNotesSharing")!
    userDefaulte.setObject(data, forKey: "file")     
    userDefaulte.synchronize()

}
```

I saved the data object. 
now I want to send it to the keyboard and decode and put in an array

then in `KeyboardViewController.swift`

load the data:

```
if userDefaulte.objectForKey("file") != nil {
 var userDefaulte = NSUserDefaults(suiteName: "group.Allegretti.ShortcutsNotesSharing")!
            var fileSalvataggio = userDefaulte.objectForKey("file") as NSData
            scatola =  NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(fileSalvataggio) as [NoteModel]
        }
```

the object specifically arrives in the keyboard but I get this error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException', reason: '*** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver decodeObjectForKey:]: cannot decode object of class (Shortcuts.NoteModel)'
```

Comment: Did you implement `init(coder decoder: NSCoder)` in the class?

Comment: yes in the class NoteModel

Comment: You put a breakpoint in NoteModel? What happened?

Comment: in NoteModel everything works. in KeyboardViewController.swift not work. this code:  scatola =  NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(fileSalvataggio) as [NoteModel] crash the keyboard and put the error

Comment: link code NoteModel https://www.dropbox.com/s/tv4nbx75r0545p4/Schermata%202014-10-29%20alle%2020.39.36.png?dl=0